# WhatsApp notifications make phone unusable!

Tags: notifications, whatsapp-messenger

When I get am SMS text message I get a small notification at the top of the screen. However when I get a WhatsApp message the notification takes over the entire screen. If I get a flurry of messages my phone is basically unusable for a while, which is annoying if I'm trying to do something else.

I don't want to turn off WhatsApp notifications completely I just want them to be less prominent. Is this possible? I have a Pixel 3 so I'm running stock Android.

Comment: WhatsApp settings > Notifications > disable 'Use high priority notifications'

Comment: Open WhatsApp settings->notification->turn off pop up notification for both group and message notifications